# PHP - XAMPP cannot load pages when the sessions file is included

Tags: php, session, xampp

I am trying to include sessions in my website, and have create an includes file called `session.inc.php`. Just to check the mechanics of the session are working, I have only included the `session_start()` command, and some data is applied to session variables once the user has completed the login process.

The only problem is I can't even get this far, as soon as I use the following line of code:

```
//allow session to hold between pages
require_once("includes/sessions.inc.php");
```

the pages with this command in the PHP script at the top of the page will not even load. I have absolutely no idea why this is.

Am I missing a basic XAMPP setting or something that allows sessions to run? Or is XAMPP just not up to running sessions?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: I would make sure error reporting is turned on or check the error log for output

Comment: Please can you show us your debug results?

Comment: GET http://localhost/BetPlace/startbootstrap-business-casual-1.0.4/index.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - called on line one of my index page.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - called on the entire index file